# Blank React.JS results

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Using URL: http://localhost:3000/

After running the cmd: npm start. (In a frontend terminal)
And running the cmd: python manage.py runserver (In a backend terminal)

This is the app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/');
      const todos = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        todos
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            <span>{item.description}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://www.localhost:3000',
]

#API PERMISSIONS
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'crispy_forms',
    'todo.apps.TodoConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I am attempting to create todos based on this tutorial: https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-react-tutorial/

There should currently be three todos displayed. (I've confirmed these three todos are in the database and under the admin screen).

Comment: What does the console log says ? Does the Django development server says it got any request ?

Comment: I think you have to check the server response. react side everything looks correct